# How can I automatically shift choice options between two different list items?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I'm trying to create a library check-in/check-out system using google forms where an when an option is checked out, it automatically moves from the 'Check Out?' list to the 'Check In?' list (or is deleted from the check out and added to the check in list).

I apologize if this has been answered, but I have been unable to find out how to make it work. I don't really know what I'm doing so what I wrote is an absolute fraken-code from things that looks applicable on this site. (Also, I think I might have gotten myself deeply confused when setting all my variables.)

Here is my code, it is linked to a Form with two drop down lists, titled "Check Out?" and "Check In?". I am looking to change the drop down lists and add a Choice when that Choice is selected on the form on the other list. The function is set up to run when the form submits.

```
function updateLibraryForm(){
  var form = FormApp.getActiveForm(); 
  var formResponse = form.getResponses();
  for (var i = 0; i < formResponse.length; i++) {
  var formResponse = formResponse[i];
    var itemResponses = formResponse.getItemResponses();

  for (var i=0; i<itemResponses.length; i++) {
    switch (itemResponses[i].getItem().getTitle()) {
      case "Check Out?":
        var out = itemResponses[i].getResponse(); 
        break;

if (item.getTitle() === "Check Out?"){
     var thingsthatareout = item.asListItem()
     }
if (item.getTitle() === "Check In?"){
     var thingsthatarein = item.asListItem()
     }

var availabletobecheckedout = thingsthatarein.getChoices ()
var availabletobecheckedin = thingsthatareout.getChoices ()

thingsthatareout.push(getItembyTitle("Check In?").createChoice(out));
listitem.setChoices(thingsthatareout);

       case "Check In?":
        var notout = itemResponses[i].getResponse();
        break;


thingsthatarein.push(getItembyTitle("Check Out?").createChoice(notout));
listitem.setChoices(thingsthatarein);


    }
  }  
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

### Recommendation

I included some sample of a form modifying itself on submission below, however what you really should know is that *Forms is not a good route for what you wish to achieve.*

You have a fundamental problem of if a user opens the form, sees it's available to checkout, but someone else checks it out during the time they reviewed the form, the user may still click the "check out" and there's nothing that can be done to prevent this or inform the user (at that moment) of the issue.

While this may not be often, certainly people open forms and get distracted, and then maybe 5 minutes later they click submit. You would then could have two submissions of "check out" and there is no way to prevent this from happening as you cannot have forms update on the fly.

Thus, you'd have to write more code to account for such a situation, and probably create an email alert to inform the user your form didn't do what it said it was going to do.

Nevertheless.... if that's of no concern, then maybe this will help.

### Sample of Form Updating A Checklist

While not technically the same as yours, here's an example of a form that updates its own checklist by removing items immediately after submission. I've included some comments which you might be able to apply

When the user submits a response, the below app scripts are run and the items that were checked are removed.

```
//Constants
const thisForm = FormApp.getActiveForm();
const zLatestResponse = thisForm.getResponses()[thisForm.getResponses().length - 1];
const itemDailyID = ??????;//update this with the item ID number

/**
 * Executed when new entry received. Must setup trigger
 */
function entryMade(e) {
  reviewResponse_(e.response);
}

function reviewResponse_(zResponse) {
  // creates an array of items check
  var theTasksCompleted = zResponse.getResponseForItem(thisForm.getItemById(itemDailyID)).getResponse();

  //it items were checked, then it launches below function to update form
  if (theTasksCompleted.length > 0) {
    updateCompletedTasks_(theTasksCompleted, thisForm.getItemById(itemDailyID));
  }
}

function updateCompletedTasks_(zCompleted, zItem) {
  const textForNone = "All Tasks Complete" // text if everything completed

  //array of old choices
  var oldChoices = zItem.asCheckboxItem().getChoices().map(x => x.getValue());

  //modified old array that excludes checked members
  var newChoices = oldChoices.filter(x => !zCompleted.includes(x));

  //condition for everything checked.
  if (newChoices.length == 0) {
    newChoices.push(textForNone);
  } else {
    //sorts list alphabetically
    newChoices.sort();
  }
  //updates item with new choices
  zItem.asCheckboxItem().setChoiceValues(newChoices);

}
```

Screenshot of front end
[image: Front end view]

Comment: Thank you very much! Just curious, is there an online system you would recommend for my project?

Comment: yea... a website, sql, microsoft dataverse, sap. Maybe have them interact directly with google sheets so it's live. If you wouldn't mind clicking `accept` it'd be appreciated. While probably not what you hoped for, it is the answer to your question.